# Как на стороне сервера получить Fragment ID из URL

Tags: php, веб-сервер, php7

Как получить из PHP Fragment ID из URL для дальнейшей работы с ним?
Я прочитал много форумов и статей, и я понял, что это невозможно. Вот и хочу уточнить, действительно ли это невозможне или же есть путь к решению этой задачи?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Fragment ID - то что находится после #. (Например example.com/page.php#fragmentid)

Comment: это якорь для html эл-та...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, действительно, это невозможно. Мне придётся искать обходной путь.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/587719)

Comment: @Jack_oS утверждение «это невозможно» как раз является вполне полноценным ответом